# Django Model Validation to ensure a Object can't be Child of itself and parent of its children/ grand Children

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a case where I have a WBS, which has a parent_wbs field as Foreign key.
I am trying to ensure that User don't keep adding child of a WBS so a Limit of Max 4 dept. Secondly I also want to ensure, that on edit I am not saving an object as parent of itself or an object shouldn't be set as parent who is also child/ grand child of current Object.

```
    class WBS(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent_wbs = models.ForeignKey('WBS', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  # This field will be automatically updated on each save
    modified_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)  # You can specify your own logic for updating this field

    def is_valid_descendant(self, parent_wbs, max_depth=4):
        """
        Check if this WBS is a valid descendant (child or grandchild) of the provided WBS,
        and also ensure that the depth of the relationship is not greater than max_depth.
        """
        current_wbs = self
        depth = 0

        while current_wbs and depth <= max_depth:
            if current_wbs == parent_wbs:
                return False
            current_wbs = current_wbs.parent_wbs
            depth += 1

        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my form validation

```
    class WBSForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WBS
        fields = ['id', 'num', 'name', 'parent_wbs']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
        self.fields['parent_wbs'].widget.attrs['required'] = False


    def clean_parent_wbs(self):
        other_wbs = self.cleaned_data.get('parent_wbs')
        # instance_id = self.instance.id if self.instance else None  # Get instance ID or None if it's a new object


        if other_wbs and self.instance:
            # Check if the current WBS is a descendant of the selected parent_wbs
            if not self.instance.is_valid_descendant(other_wbs):
                raise ValidationError("A WBS cannot be its own parent or a child of its children (! >4 Levels Deep)")

        return other_wbs
```